# ActionScript 2 character selection

Tags: button, movieclip, actionscript-2

I haven't been able to make a character selection in [ActionScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript) 2 so what is an example that, if I click on this button, a movieclip comes out in this frame?

Comment: Sorry, but this question is too vague to even try to answer it in its current form.  Can you try to explain more fully what you are trying to do and what is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Frame 1:

```
movieClip1.alpha = 0;
movieClip1.stop();
movieClip2.alpha = 0;
movieClip2.stop();
movieClip3.alpha = 0;
movieClip3.stop();
button1.onPress = function() {
movieClip1.alpha = 100;
movieClip1.play();
}
button2.onPress = function() {
movieClip2.alpha = 100;
movieClip2.play();
}
button3.onPress = function() {
movieClip3.alpha = 100;
movieClip3.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like the below. I haven;t tested this so it prob won;t compile but it'll be very close. Basically put this on a single empty frame on the main timeline. make sure you have button and character movieclips all with export settings and linkage identifiers set. Modify code below and see what happens.

```
var numButtons:Number = 10; //number of buttons you want
var buttonMovieClipName:String = "button"; //linkage identifier of button
var startX:Number = 10; //start x position
var startY:Number = 500;  //start y position
var dist:Number = 10; //distance between buttons
var characters:Array = {"A","B","C","D"};  //linkage names of your characters
var currentChar:MovieClip = null;

for(var i:Number = 0; i < numButtons; i++)
{
   this.attachMovie("button", "button"+i, this.getNextHighestDepth());
   this["button"+i]._x = startX + (i*(dist+this["button"+i]._width]));        
   this["button"+i]._y = startY;
   this["button"+i].character = characters[i];
   this["button"+i].onPress = displayCharacter; 
}

function displayCharacter():void
{
   var par = this._parent;

   //remove previous character on stage
   if(currentChar != null)
   {
       removeMovieClip(par[currentChar]);
   }

   par.attachMovie(this.character, this.character, par.getNextHighestDepth()); //atach character
   par[this.character]._x = 400;  //set to whatever
   par[this.character]._y = 300;  //set to whatever
   currentChar = this.character; //set current character to this
}
```